# How to avoid loading viewControllers/views when app is launched in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm working on an app that can get launched in the background due to location events. From the logs I see that when this happens my initial viewController also gets loaded. Is there a way to only load when application actually becomes active? The initial view controller is set through storyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: How does one "launch" an app in the background? AFAIK, only the user can launch an app. That is, s/he must touch an icon in order to launch it.

Comment: Applications can get launched in the background due a number of reasons, one that I know of is location-based reminder apps. application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: will get called with options dictionary indicating this event.

Comment: You must have *something* set as your root view controller when didFinishLaunching returns.

Comment: Aaron, I'm not setting the self.window.rootViewController manually, it is already populated when application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is called, it's probably set because the initial scene is configured in Storyboard. I think @danh 's answer is probably what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the automatic setup of the app's window as follows: select the initial view controller in storyboard, go to the attributes inspector and unselect "Initial Scene -> Is initial View Controller".  This will generate a warning, since the scene is now unreachable.  Go to the identity inspector and set a Storyboard ID.

In order for the app to work normally when you want it to, setup the window manually...

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    BOOL condition = /* whatever condition that makes you want to present the UI */
    if (!application.keyWindow.rootViewController && condition) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        // use the your view controller subclass here if you've made one
        UIViewController *vc= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"the identifier"];
    application.keyWindow.rootViewController = vc;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and I'm getting the following error before applicationDidBecomeActive is called: "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?"

Comment: removing 'Main storyboard file base name' from info.plist removes the error but haven't got it to completely work. Will report soon.

Comment: Do you really want to do this every time the app becomes active?

Comment: @danh could you look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584566/how-to-stop-handle-ui-operations-in-ios-when-app-moves-to-background-state

Answer (score 0):

Set up a location manager in your App Delegate and handle the location events there. Set the App Delegate as that location manager's delegate.

Comment: I have a separate singleton class handling my location manager stuff, so that's not really the problem. How can I avoid loading my main ViewController and load it only if application becomes active? My main ViewController gets automatically loaded through the storyboard and there is probably something very simple I'm missing. thanks.