# How to stop/handle UI Operations in iOS when app moves to background state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-background-mode

My app can be launched via `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` in the background. In that case the usual flow to setup `initail view controller` and some animations on the app's landing-page/first-page of the app take place.

My question is, Is this a good practice, If I leave these animations like this even when my app is launched via OS in background? Three things I am concerned about:

1. Some animations are continuous, like a `circular-dot(UIImage)` expanding and shrinking, using CAAnimation.
2. Some views are added and removed as subviews to the `keyWindow`, based on user location.
3. When user taps the home button, do I need to stop the animations and subview additions then also?

Making the animation stop and resume via `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` seems tedious.

Comment: Could we look at your app delegate code?  You should be able to distinguish what sort of app start is taking place based on the invocation of `application: didReceiveLocalNotification:`

Comment: @danh `application: didReceiveLocalNotification` is not called. My app wakes up in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` and the `launchOptions` key has the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey `. Also, when my animation code executes (no matter in which state my app is) I request main queue using dispatch and perform UI operations there. So far, everything is working fine. And since, these particular animations occur via a singleton class, I did not have to request main queue everywhere in the app